# mean for different variables in each iteration

Tags: r, variables, mean

I am a beginner in r. I have selected a bootstrap sample and some variables are randomly selected and estimated in each iteration. Following result shows the selected variables and their corresponding estimated values in each iteration:

```
 variables       values
1      Var7 0.0006557896
2      Var9 0.0000000000
3      Var6 0.3853748481
4      Var1 0.0185577608
5      Var5 0.6290157597
  variables      values
1      Var9  0.00000000
2      Var2 -0.16837159
3      Var1  0.06709587
4      Var6  0.83189224
5      Var8  0.24698713
  variables     values
1      Var6 0.00000000
2      Var8 0.68304756
3      Var5 0.88862385
4      Var3 0.00000000
5      Var1 0.00422016
```

Now, i want to compute the mean for different variables selected in each iteration. How could i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how the iterations are stored.  Assuming that we get the output stored in a `list`, then `rbind` the datasets then do a group by `mean`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[, .(values = mean(values)),
          by = variables][order(variables)]
#    variables        values
#1:      Var1  0.0299579303
#2:      Var2 -0.1683715900
#3:      Var3  0.0000000000
#4:      Var5  0.7588198049  
#5:      Var6  0.4057556960
#6:      Var7  0.0006557896
#7:      Var8  0.4650173450
#8:      Var9  0.0000000000
```

Comment: I've run the for loop as below for iterations:                                                             for (j in 1:10){
com<-cbind(variables[[j]], c[[j]])
print(com)
}

Comment: @Fakhra  If  `com` is preassigned as a list `com <- vector('list", 10)` in the `for` loop `com[[j]] <- cbind(...`

Comment: I've tried to preassign "com" as a list then                                      
`com[[j]]<-cbind(variables[[j]],c[[j]]) `                                                                    but the output is:                                                                                           `[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
  variables    values
1      Var9 0.0000000
2      Var8 0.4116439
3     Var10 0.6056728
4      Var2 0.0000000
5      Var5 0.7528453`

Comment: @Fakhra Do you have `c` and `variables` as `list` or not?

Comment: I have one more confusion as i run the code sometimes it gives an error but sometimes it give the results. plus another question is that if i get the desired list saved in `com` and when i run ` rbindlist(list(com[[1]], com[[2]], com[[3]]))[, .(values = mean(values)),
          by = variables][order(variables)] ` ,I have to call `com[[1]]:[[10]]` so should i call separately `com` as `com[[1]]` then `com[[2]]` and so on. or there is any other way of calling `com[[1]]:com[[10]]`

Comment: @Fakhra  It is not clear about the structure of your data.  What i meant is that suppose you have defined `com <- vector("list", 10)` and each of the `variables` and `c` are both list with 10 elements then the assignment should work.  You didn't provide any info about `variables` or `c`

Comment: Actually i have selected bootstrap samples and it was iterated 10 times. for each iteration i have randomly selected some variables and applied penalized logistic regression. `variables` contain the variables' names selected in each iteration and `c` contains the values of those estimated coefficients. then i have to compute the mean for coefficient estimates of each variable selected in different iterations.

Comment: If both of them are `list` of vectors then the `cbind` should work